# sort a dimension in crossfilter - d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js

This is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/55ZW5/1/).

I'm trying to show the show the top 100 rows in descending order of a column.

Suppose I have a dimension, how do it sort it?

Came across [this](http://bl.ocks.org/phoebebright/raw/3822981/). But couldn't fine anythign useful.

Help me in sorting the data in `descending` order on the value column.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a dimension, it will sort the data for you using a dual-pivot quick sort algorithm.  Calling [dimension.top(n)](https://github.com/square/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#wiki-dimension_top) will return you the top documents back.  Vice versa, calling [dimension.bottom(n)](https://github.com/square/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#wiki-dimension_bottom), will return you the bottom most documents.  It will be the natural sort order, so if you want all the documents back sorted descending, use:

```
var sortedDescending = dimension.top(Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY);
```

Comment: To get the unique values of a dimension, you'll want to first group on that dimension and then call top:
`dimension.group().top(Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY)` 
or
`dimension.group().all()` 

These do the same thing.  This will return a naturally sorted list of objects by their keys.  The objects take the form of:

`{key: "abc", value: 20}`

The keys are the values from the dimension, values are generated from crossfilters reduce function and could be overlooked in your case.

Comment: Also it might be worth taking a look at [d3.nest](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#wiki-d3_nest).